# Arduino MAX6675 k-thermocouple unexpected output and response

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm developing a data logger with a MAX6675 k-type thermocouple hooked into an Arduino Uno. I've followed all the tutorials and checked and double checked my connections, but I'm getting real weird output in the serial plotter as seen in the  figure attached.

[serial plotter output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYsVD.jpg)

[image]

What's more is that when I hold up a naked flame to the themocouple sensor or any other kind of heat source, it changes the amplitude of oscillation which isn't what I'd expect.

Finally, the temperature values themselves don't really seem to make much sense as it's settling at about the 220 to 240 range. It doesn't match celsius readings as I coded it to read, and is too low to be in Kelvin and too high to be Fahrenheit.

Thanks in advance, it's probably something simple, but I've been butting my head against this for two days, trying different libraries, etc. but no luck.

My code is below, I've got a toggle switch to activate the data logging and LEDs to tell me if it's logging or not.

```
#include <max6675.h>

//Thermocouple
int ktcSO = 8;
int ktcCS = 9;
int ktcCLK = 10;

MAX6675 ktc(ktcCLK, ktcCS, ktcSO);

//Toggle
int switchPin = 7;
int switchValue = 0;

float sensorVals[] = {0};

void setup() {     
  pinMode (6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (5, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);      
  switchValue = digitalRead(switchPin);
  if (switchValue == 1) {
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
    sensorVals[0] = analogRead(ktc.readCelsius());    
    Serial.println(sensorVals[0]); 
  }
  else  {
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading the analog value of the pin corresponding to the measured temperature in Celsius? And what's the point of the array with one element?

Comment: Array is going to have pressure sensor data later as well. As for the analog choice,  when I tried the code with a digitalRead I got nothing coming up on the serial plotter, but analog seemed to work just fine.

Comment: You don't need neither `analogRead` nor `digitalRead`. Where did you get the idea of using them? [The examples are pretty clear](https://github.com/adafruit/MAX6675-library/blob/master/examples/serialthermocouple/serialthermocouple.pde).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That's giving me much more believable values, though it's not reacting to any heat stimulus anymore. Or only updating when I flick the switch off and on again, but never above 32°C even with a flame.